# I can't figure out why it's saying that the matcher function is undefined.

Tags: javascript

This code is designed to identify an array of anagrams for a string given an array of possible anagrams.

```
var anagram = function(input) {
    return input.toLowerCase();
}
```

I'm adding the matcher function here to the String prototype.

```
String.prototype.matcher = function(remainingLetters) {
    var clone = this.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < clone.length; i++) {
        if (clone[i].indexOf(remainingLetters) > -1) {
            remainingLetters.splice(clone[i].indexOf(remainingLetters, 1));
            clone.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    if (remainingLetters.length == 0 && clone.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
a
String.prototype.matches = function(matchWordArray) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; matchWordArray.length; i++) {
        var remainingLetters = this.split("");
        if (matchWordArray[i].matcher(remainingLetters)) {
            result.push(arrayToMatch[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var a = anagram("test");
a.matches(["stet", "blah", "1"]);

module.exports = anagram;
```

Comment: Is that 'a' before the String.prototype.matches definition messing things up for you?

Comment: There are a few issues. You have a stray `a` in the code, `arrayToMatch` doesn't exist in `String.prototype.matches`, and your `for` loop doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < matchWordArray.length; i++) {
```

The original statement:

```
for (var i = 0; matchWordArray.length; i++) {
```

...would result in an infinite loop because matchWordArray.length is always truthy (3) in your test.